# Dlib face points to appear in thresh

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

I am detecting blue color with opencv. Along with it I am detecting dlib face points. So I gave them blue color and want them to appear in my thresh. The issue is that my code is giving the points blue color and I am getting them in the cv frame but it is not appearing in my thresh.

Below is the code I have written so far:

```
from imutils import face_utils
import imutils
import numpy as np
import dlib
import cv2

thresh = 0.25
frame_check = 20
detect = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predict = dlib.shape_predictor(
    "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")  # Dat file is the crux of the code


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
flag = 0
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=450)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    subjects = detect(gray, 0)
    for subject in subjects:
        shape = predict(gray, subject)
        shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)  # converting to NumPy Array
        for (i, (x, y)) in enumerate(shape):
            frame=cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 2, (255, 0, 0), -1)


    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array([110, 50, 50]), np.array([130, 255, 255]))
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask2)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    median = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

    kernel_square = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    dilation = cv2.dilate(median, kernel_square, iterations=2)
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(dilation, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_square)

    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(opening, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    # thresh = thresh[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1]
    cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.stop()
```

Can dlib transfer the points to thresh or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should draw the points again in the thresh image, because after a lot of steps of process, those points can be eliminated. Something like that

```
...
shapes = []
for subject in subjects:
    shape = predict(gray, subject)
    shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)  # converting to NumPy Array
    shapes.append(shape)
    for (i, (x, y)) in enumerate(shape):
        frame=cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 2, (255, 0, 0), -1)
...
for shape in shapes:
    for (i, (x, y)) in enumerate(shape):
        thresh=cv2.circle(thresh, (x, y), 2, 255, -1) # thresh is a gray image
```